# how to get the app package name by javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Our H5 page will open in another app.now I need to get the package name of the app. I am trying to find the answer, but failed.
anyone can tell me what should I do?

Comment: Description is too short to analyze what your situation/problem is. Show some thing that you have tried so far or explain it a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can achieve by using cordova plugin `cordova-plugin-app-version`

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-app-version`

```
cordova.getAppVersion.getPackageName(function(name){
    console.log('Package - Name : ', name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `window.platform.name`. You can get current app name.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).